Code insights unavailable on Android Studio

I got this error with android studio, I'm lost Idk how I got this and how to solve it, I got a plugin error, I followed someone one stackoverflow that suggested to delete the cache folder (mine was about 10gb) then I got this error, is there a way to solve this??
help
I tried googling , chatgpting it but no solution

If you didn't already try it when deleting your cache manually, there is also the File -> Invalidate caches option in Android Studio which will also restart the IDE.
